# Extending Netbeans Python Plugin

Tags: python, netbeans-platform, netbeans-plugins

We link to extend(https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-projectextension.html) and add some functionality to Netbean Python plug-in. For that, we needed to know the projectType of that plugin. Where can we get it.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since you asked this question, but if you are still looking for this, here is a link to python code base. Look inside the `layer.xml` file. That is where the project type is configured.

http://hg.netbeans.org/main/contrib/file/f4cca47a6b88/python.project/src/org/netbeans/modules/python/project/layer.xml